# Remove/add value onfocus/onblur if empty in jquery, input field

Tags: jquery

I know there exists many questions about this, but I dont know what to search.

I have a email field, and I want it to have "Write your email here" and when you click/do onfocus it should disappear. Although if you did not write something and go onblur it should appear again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### 1. Markup

```
<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="Write your email here" />
```

#### 2. jQuery

```
$('#email')
  .on('focus', function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      if($this.val() == 'Write your email here'){
          $this.val('');
      }
  })
  .on('blur', function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      if($this.val() == ''){
          $this.val('Write your email here');
      }
  });​
```

#### 3. Demo

[**jQuery input placeholder**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/aujqU/)

Answer (score 4):

You should use HTML5 placeholder instead and use a jquery plugin for older browsers
http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/forms.html

Running example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/AamkB/

There are a lot of jquery plugins for placeholder, i used this one:
http://webcloud.se/code/jQuery-Placeholder/

Answer (score 4):

You can use the inline JavaScript tags onblur / onfocus . Maybe not the most 'clean' HTML code but it certainly works in all browsers! (Didn't try IE5.5 / 6.0, but hey, who is using these oldies nowadays?! ^_^)

```
<input type="text" name="aSweetInputField" value="Your textfield value" 
class="anyClass"  onclick="if (this.defaultValue==this.value) this.value=''" 
onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue">
```

That's it!

Comment: `placeholder` attribute is a better solution, together with a js plugin for browsers who don't support this attribute

Comment: True, but on the fly this would be a great second-best. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You do not need any JS for that. Simply use `placeholder="Write your email here."` in the `<input>` tag.

If you need to support IE, add http://webcloud.se/code/jQuery-Placeholder/ to make it work there, too.

Comment: Holy molly. This is a big step forward for me O.o Which browsers support it?

Comment: It's worth noting that this is an HTML 5 attribute. :)

Comment: FF3.7+ Safari4.0+ Chrome4.0+ opera 11.0+ iphone4.0+. http://diveintohtml5.org/forms.html

Comment: @cenanozen - the diveinto URL has changed (been mirrored) to http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" 
onfocus="if($(this).val() == 'Write your email here') $(this).val('')" onblur="if($(this).val() == '') $(this).val('Write your email here')" 
value="Write your email here">
```

There you go.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for Forms globally, just define values initially in the input's `value` attribute.

```html
<input type="text" name="example" value="example text"> 
<textarea name="exampleTextArea" value="example text in textarea">
```

```javascript
var el = $('input[type=text], textarea');
    el.focus(function(e) {
        if (e.target.value == e.target.defaultValue)
            e.target.value = '';
    });
    el.blur(function(e) {
        if (e.target.value == '')
            e.target.value = e.target.defaultValue;
});
```